# KML and Spot and Swipe widget in flexviewer 2.2

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-flex-api, flex

1. I found the KML widget for Flex viewer but I was not able to make it work properly. Can anybody have any link for that.
2. I came across SPOT and SWIPE tool code, but the links to download the code redirected to something else. I thing the links are dead. So any body have that code or widget for SPOT and SWIPE tool.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written one and posted it in the code gallery, not all KMLs are supported yet, but loads a few basic ones.  Hope it works from you.  This is for ArcGIS Flex 2.4....

http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=d6b993ef803249f486e83edd3f94239b

Answer (score 2):

The download link for the old Swipe & Spotlight tool is http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=16566

Note that this was build with Adobe 3.x SDK and will not work with Adobe Flex 4.0/4.1/4.5 SDKs.

Comment: I need new ones that should work with Flex 4.